# Periodic Jobs not registered in Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have sidkiq configured as following.

```
# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

require 'sidekiq/web'
Sidekiq::Web.use(Rack::Protection, origin_whitelist: ['https://mysite'])

redis_config = { url: ENV['SIDEKIQ_REDIS_URL'] }

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = redis_config
  config.average_scheduled_poll_interval = 1
  config.periodic do |mgr|
    mgr.register('* 2 * * *', 'MyPeriodicWorker') # 2am daily
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = redis_config
end
```

After I built docker image locally, I ran it from my laptop and it did work.

```
[Patch] Preventing bunny channel leak
2020-11-26T09:01:45.452Z pid=1 tid=gq3ufhkop INFO: Booting Sidekiq 6.0.7 with redis options 
{:url=>"redis://127.0.0.1:56379/4"}
2020-11-26T09:01:46.705Z pid=1 tid=gq3ufhkop INFO: Booted Rails 6.0.3.1 application in 
staging environment
2020-11-26T09:01:46.705Z pid=1 tid=gq3ufhkop INFO: Running in ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 
revision 67812) [x86_64-linux-musl]
2020-11-26T09:01:46.705Z pid=1 tid=gq3ufhkop INFO: Sidekiq Pro 5.0.1 / Sidekiq Enterprise 
2.0.1, commercially licensed.
2020-11-26T09:01:46.721Z pid=1 tid=gq3v7vxkt INFO: Managing 1 periodic jobs
2020-11-26T09:01:46.724Z pid=1 tid=gq3v7vxkt INFO: Gained leadership of the cluster
```

But when I deployed it to k8s cluster, it didn't.

```
[Patch] Preventing bunny channel leak
2020-11-26T08:17:01.324Z pid=1 tid=gtmxb31mt INFO: Booting Sidekiq 6.0.7 with redis options 
{:url=>"redis://:REDACTED@myredisinstance:6379/4"}
2020-11-26T08:17:02.406Z pid=1 tid=gtmxb31mt INFO: Booted Rails 6.0.3.1 application in 
staging environment
2020-11-26T08:17:02.406Z pid=1 tid=gtmxb31mt INFO: Running in ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 
revision 67812) [x86_64-linux-musl]
2020-11-26T08:17:02.406Z pid=1 tid=gtmxb31mt INFO: Sidekiq Pro 5.0.1 / Sidekiq Enterprise 
2.0.1, commercially licensed.
```

What makes the difference?

Answer (score 1):

In a cluster, only one Sidekiq process manages/enqueues the periodic jobs (otherwise duplicate Sidekiq processes would create duplicate periodic jobs!). Your example process did not get cluster leadership and so is not in control of the periodic jobs.

Comment: I only have one replica for pods labelled as `sidekiq` instance, which means there is  supposed to be only one instance and it is the leader. Since k8s adopts rolling update mechanism, which means, it tried to create a new pod and test liveliness and if it was ok, it would kill old pod. Will this cause the loss of leadership, that is, new pod did not gain leadership and old pod with leadership was killed?

Comment: Let me propose another question, is there an explicit way to grant a sidekiq process leadership? I mean some code in rails console like `Sidekiq.list_processes` to show all processes along with id or uuid and `Sidekiq.set_leader_process 'some_id_or_uuid'`

Comment: Leadership is all handled automatically. If an old process is terminated, a new process will pick it up within a minute.

Answer (score 0):

On k8 `mgr.register('* 2 * * *', 'MyPeriodicWorker')` command is not executing. Try to echo at that time. Maybe you are not having permission to update crontab. and may be you need to use `sudo` somehow.

Comment: You can debug it inside your Kubernetes pod.